# Python file for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, key, text-files

I am new to python so excuse my stupidity. I am trying to iterate over a dictionary that is in a file (.txt). However, I only want to iterate over the keys from the dictionary, not the values. I have been trying for hours but have made no progress. Thanks for the help.

```
kluizen = {
    11;kaasstengel,
    1;geheim,
    5;kluisvanpietje,
    12;z@terd@g
 } #the number of a locker with the password afterwards.

f = open('fa_kluizen.txt', 'r') 
contents = f.read() 
print(contents) 

for numbers in contents: print(numbers) 
f.close()
```

Comment: `for key in dictionary:` If you iterate over a dictionary, you get the keys.

Comment: Share your tries (code) and a sample of you file

Comment: Edit your post when adding more info, not in comment and explain what is what

Comment: You should use colons in you dictionary not semi-colons. Does the text file you're importing have semi-colons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file does not contain a dictionary, as you cannot store literally a Python dictionary in a file.

But I agree with you it looks like a dictionary in the sense that it has information organized in key value pairs.

You're interested in getting the keys out of there: that is the number of the locker.

```
mykeys = []

with open('fa_kluizen.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if ';' in line:
            key, value = line.strip().split(';')

            mykeys.append(key)


# now we have it in mykeys list

for key in mykeys:
    print(key)
```

Please try this:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import json

with open("path/to/file.txt", "r") as f:
    # read the file as dictionary
    file_as_dict = json.load(f) 

    # iterate over the keys
    for key in file_as_dict:
        print(key)
```